# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BookingsController#create Couldn't find Hotel without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my bookings controller
I am facing problem in create action, I cant get the hotel id there.
I need to get the hotel id in the bookings controller of create action.
I tried member routing but faced problems in path, I need a direct approach to solve the problem

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @booking = Booking.new
    @single = Room.joins(:hotel).where("hotel_id = ?", params[:hotel_id]).pluck(:single_bedroom_num)
    @double = Room.joins(:hotel).where("hotel_id = ?", params[:hotel_id]).pluck(:double_bedroom_num)
    @suite = Room.joins(:hotel).where("hotel_id = ?", params[:hotel_id]).pluck(:suite_room_num)
    @dormitory = Room.joins(:hotel).where("hotel_id = ?", params[:hotel_id]).pluck(:dormitory_room_num)
    s = params[:single_bedroom_num]
    d = params[:double_bedroom_num]
    su = params[:suite_room_num]
    dor = params[:dormitory_room_num]
  end

  def index
  end

  def create
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @booking = Booking.new(book_params)
    if @booking.save
    flash.now.alert = "booked successfully!"
    redirect_to root_path
    else
    flash.now.alert = "Oops, couldn't book."
    render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    check_in = params[:check_in_date]
    check_out = params[:check_out_date]
    @single = Room.single_bedroom_num
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def book_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:id, :num_of_guests, :guest_name, :check_in_date, :check_out_date, :single_bedroom_num, :double_bedroom_num, :suite_room_num, :dormitory_room_num, :hotel_name, :hotel_id, :room_id)
  end

end
```

Comment: why do you need `@hotel` if you do not use it in the action? Also please show params hash or try to reach `:hotel_id` as `book_params[:hotel_id]` if it presents in the permitted params hash

Comment: @RomanAlekseiev The only reasonable usage of `Hotel.find` I can see is that it ensures the hotel really does exist - i.e. you can't manipulate parameters to accidentally create a booking for a non-existent hotel. However, one might expect this to be a model validation, not something to be handled in the controller... And as you say, the `@hotel` variable appears unused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct but not wise approach is passing hotel_id in params from where you are hitting the controller action. Like this:

```
new_booking_path(hotel_id: hotel.id)

# hotel must be known here in view that is

# or you can name it anything like h or abc or xxx
```

Better way is to use Restful routing like:

```
   resources :hotels do
      resources :bookings
   end
```

Answer (score 1):

in the post-path of your view, just provide the hotel_id.

```
<%= form_for ... :url => xxx_path(hotel_id: @hotel.id)  %>
```